# python beautifulsoup add attribute to tag without value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I need to add async attribute to the tag using beautifulsoup and python.

given this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

I need to get this:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

I'm trying this:

```
newTag.attrs['async'] = ''
```

but the result is:

```
<script async="" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve], including all the relevant version numbers? When I try this, doing the obvious, it works. If you're doing something weird to get the soup, or using old or bleeding-edge versions, we need to know that to debug it.

Comment: I don't think that's valid xml and I wouldn't expect you can.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `newTag.attrs['async'] = None`:

```
from urllib import request
f = request.urlopen("http://www.example.com")
s = f.read()
f.close()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")

newTag = soup.find("meta", charset = "utf-8")

tagCopy = newTag

newTag.attrs['async'] = ""
print(newTag)

tagCopy.attrs['async'] = None
print(tagCopy)
```

This produces the following output:

```
<meta async="" charset="utf-8"/>
<meta async charset="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: That creates a second element, but it's not added in the soup, while the old element still has async="". Trying to replace the old with the new old.replaceWith(new), the async still comes with the value between the quotes. Really confusing for me.

Comment: Have you tried running the code in the very first line of my answer `newTag.attrs['async'] = None`? The rest of the code is just an example of how the output differs between `None` and `""`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. Yes, it’s generating empty quotes. What’s weird is that when when you print it displays without quotes, but when you send it elsewhere or write the output, the quotes show up.